# How to make chartjs chart with time y-axis?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, charts, chart.js

I have data something like this:

```
{
"measurements": [
{
  "id": 10,
  "key": "Demoo",
  "value": "00:00:03.733;",
  "date": "2023-02-08",
  "time": "11:05",
  "value_time_formatted": "00:00:03.733"
},
{
  "id": 11,
  "key": "Demooo 2",
  "value": "00:00:05.191;",
  "date": "2023-02-08",
  "time": "11:31",
  "value_time_formatted": "00:00:05.191"
},
{
  "id": 12,
  "key": "Demo 22",
  "value": "00:00:03.002;",
  "date": "2023-02-08",
  "time": "11:31",
  "value_time_formatted": "00:00:03.002"
}
]}
```

And when I try out to make a line chart from the date as labels and value_time_formatted as values I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'data' on string '00:00:03.733'
```

The code for bind chart values looks like this:

```
 this.lineBarLabels = [];
      this.lineBarValue = [];
      res.measurements.forEach(element => {
        this.lineBarLabels.push(element.date);
        this.lineBarValue.push(element.value_time_formatted);
      });

      this.lineBar = new Chart(this.linePresents.nativeElement, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: this.lineBarLabels,
    datasets: this.lineBarValue
  }
});
this.lineBar.update();
```

I tried to convert that time into milliseconds but looks so ugly on-screen and the user needs to convert it back to hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds which is so bad from customer side :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues, here the two I could spot:

- the Main error ocurres because chartjs expects a object array for the property `dataset`, so in your case you would have to change your code to something like this:

  ```
  this.lineBar = new Chart(this.linePresents.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: this.lineBarLabels,
          datasets: [{data: this.lineBarValue}]
      }
  });
  ```
- The array `this.lineBarLabels` is never set (will be a empty array), you would have to change: `this.lineBarLabels.includes(element.date);` to  `this.lineBarLabels.push(element.date);`

These are the main issues, I don't understand what output should you are looking for, and I don't think that setting the values to strings `value_time_formatted` will work, but if you fix the above mentioned points, you will be a step closer to a working chart.

**Update:**

It seems you fixed on mistake in your question, if you want to improve your code here is a tip for you time convertion ([link to relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)):

```js
const date = new Date();

// A cleaner solution
let aShortWay = date.toISOString().substring(11,23);

// Your Sode: Not really readable, and pretty long
let yourCode = (date.getUTCHours() ? (date.getUTCHours() > 9 ? date.getUTCHours() : '0' + date.getUTCHours()) : '00') + ':' +
                (date.getUTCMinutes() ? (date.getUTCMinutes() > 9 ? date.getUTCMinutes() : '0' + date.getUTCMinutes()) : '00') + ':' +
                (date.getUTCSeconds() ? (date.getUTCSeconds() > 9 ? date.getUTCSeconds() : '0' + date.getUTCSeconds()) : '00') + '.' +
                (date.getUTCMilliseconds() > 99 ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getUTCMilliseconds() > 9 ? '0' + date.getUTCMilliseconds() : '00' + date.getUTCMilliseconds());


console.info(`aShortWay Time:${aShortWay}`)
console.info(`yourCode Time:${yourCode}`)
```

Comment: I can't find a way to call the method out of createLineChart method to parse me a time in the right format so needed to be that messy :(

Comment: You just have to replace `return (date...)` with `return date.toISOString().substring(11,23); `, I don't see the problem. `getUTCMinutes()` and so are all funcitons/methodses that are called.

Comment: I just check it out. Yes, that `data.toISOString().substring(11,23)` also works well. Awesome to make code shorter :) Tnx.

Comment: can you take a look my last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75435776/why-labels-on-x-asis-does-not-shows-well

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution, hope that someone will use it in the right way :)

After this part of the code:

`res.measurements.forEach(element => { this.lineBarLabels.push(element.date); this.lineBarValue.push(element.value_time_formatted); }); this.createLineChart();`
I made this createLineChart() method to parse and render the chart:

```
public createLineChart() {
this.lineBar = new Chart(this.linePresents.nativeElement, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: this.lineBarLabels,
      datasets: [{label: this.translate.instant('time'), data: this.lineBarValue, fill: false}]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        y: {
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value) {
              const date = new Date(Number(value) * 1000);
              return date.toISOString().substring(11,23);
            }
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (context) {
              const date = new Date(Number(context.formattedValue) * 1000);
              return date.toISOString().substring(11,23);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
this.lineBar.update();
}
```

Comment: Your time construction is abit cumbersome, I update my answer to show a better solution to construct your *time*

Comment: tnx @winner_joiner we combine ideas and make great progress :) I like to meet you maybe we can work together on some app :) my email is this username on gmail be free from me some email if you like it as well :)